# jQuery sortable: object expected error when working with LI in a dynamically added OL

Tags: jquery-ui, list, jquery-ui-sortable

I am creating a simple web-based course scheduler for a department in our college and am currently developing the UI. I am creating it with jQuery UI's accordion and sortable extensions. I have it set so that you can add/delete courses and add/delete terms where the terms are all connected sortable ordered lists.

The problem I am running into is when a term is already part of the html page, everything works flawlessly. However, when you add a term OL with jQuery, courses can be added but not removed. When you try to remove the course, you get the Object Expected error. Even if you drag existing li elements from another term, you still get the Object Expected error when you try to remove them from the new term.

My thoughts are 1) I need to refresh the new term or 2) I am not initializing the new term correctly. Below is my javascript.

I can share the html code if requested, but it is just a form with buttons that call the javascript functions.

```
// Remove selected courses from term
function remCourse(term) {
var termDiv = '#term' + term + 'classes';

    $(termDiv).children().children().children(":checked").each(function() {
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
}

// Add course to term
function addCourse(term) {
var termDiv = '#term' + term + 'classes';

var course = $(termDiv).children().length + 1;

$(termDiv).append('<li class="ui-state-active"><span class="courseAction"><input name="' + term + 'c' + course + 'box" type="checkbox" /> Dept & Num: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c' + course + 'num" name="' + term + 'c' + course + 'num" size="8" maxlength="6" /> Credits: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c' + course + 'cred" name="' + term + 'c' + course + 'cred" size="4" maxlength="3" /> # of Meetings: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c' + course + 'meet" name="' + term + 'c' + course + 'meet" size="8" maxlength="6" /> Title: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c' + course + 'num" name="' + term + 'c' + course + 'num" size="20" maxlength="50" /> </span></li>'
);
}

// Remove selected terms
function remTerm() {
  $("#terms").children().children().children(":checked").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
}

// Add new term
function addTerm(term) {
var termDiv = '#term' + term + 'classes';

$("#terms").append('<div id="term' + term + '" class="connectedTerms"> <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><input class="tbox" name="t' + term + 'box" type="checkbox" />Term ' + term + '<input id="addCourse' + term + '" type="button" onclick="addCourse(this.id.substring(9))" value="Add Course" class="ui-button-text-only" /> <input id="remCourse' + term + '" type="button" onclick="removeCourse(this.id.substring(9))" value="Remove Selected Courses" class="ui-button-text-only" /> </h4> <ol id="term' + term + 'classes" class="connectedSortable"> <li class="ui-state-active"><span class="courseAction"> <input name="' + term + 'c1box" type="checkbox" /> Dept & Num: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c1num" name="' + term + 'c1num" size="8" maxlength="6" /> Credits: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c1cred" name="' + term + 'c1cred" size="4" maxlength="3" /> # of Meetings: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c1meet" name="' + term + 'c1meet" size="8" maxlength="6" /> Title: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c1num" name="' + term + 'c1num" size="20" maxlength="50" /> </span></li> </ol> </div>'
);

$(termDiv).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
}).disableSelection();

    // I tried doing a refresh below, but it just gave me an error
    // so I commented it out.
//$(termDiv).sortable('refresh');

}
```

Comment: I figured it out. It is simply a typo on my part... I will post the answer once the timer expires...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out it was a simple typo on my part. In the addTerm() javascript code, I had the the Remove Selected Courses button call the removeTerm() function instead of the remTerm() function. *sigh* Will I ever stop making typos?

The corrected code is:

```
// Add new term
function addTerm(term) {
var termDiv = '#term' + term + 'classes';

$("#terms").append('<div id="term' + term + '" class="connectedTerms"> <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><input class="tbox" name="t' + term + 'box" type="checkbox" />Term ' + term + '<input id="addCourse' + term + '" type="button" onclick="addCourse(this.id.substring(9))" value="Add Course" class="ui-button-text-only" /> <input id="remCourse' + term + '" type="button" onclick="remCourse(this.id.substring(9))" value="Remove Selected Courses" class="ui-button-text-only" /> </h4> <ol id="term' + term + 'classes" class="connectedSortable"> <li class="ui-state-active"><span class="courseAction"> <input name="' + term + 'c1box" type="checkbox" /> Dept & Num: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c1num" name="' + term + 'c1num" size="8" maxlength="6" /> Credits: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c1cred" name="' + term + 'c1cred" size="4" maxlength="3" /> # of Meetings: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c1meet" name="' + term + 'c1meet" size="8" maxlength="6" /> Title: <input type="text" id="' + term + 'c1num" name="' + term + 'c1num" size="20" maxlength="50" /> </span></li> </ol> </div>'
);

$(termDiv).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    dropOnEmpty: true,
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
}).disableSelection();

}
```